# Calling an sql file inside another sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql file with certain parameters which I need to make as generic ones.

Below is the code base in C:\sql\main.sql:

`SET @NAME = 'XYZ'`

`source C:/abc.sql`

I need all the occurences of NAME to be replaced by XYZ in abc.sql file.Which basically contains a set of insert statements.I ran the below command :

`mysql -u myusername -p DB < C:\sql\main.sql`

But after executing it throws and error saying:

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOURCE C:/abc' at line 2`

All I need to do is call an sql file C:\abc.sql in C:\sql\main.sql and then execute C:\sql\main.sql .  Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: The error message looks truncated as there is no closing single quote, please check if it is complete and attach the full message if not.

Comment: yes just modified  it. I am wondering if this is even possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this and I think the only problem with your script (`main.sql`) is the statements are not terminated with semicolons.

Try adding a semicolon to the end of the line:

```
SET @NAME = 'XYZ';
```

I was able to verify that the user-defined variable `@NAME` is in-scope when the second file (`abc.sql`) executes with the following in the second file:

```
SELECT @NAME;

# Output:
XYZ
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . one of my insert statements is as below:

`INSERT INTO Table_One(name) values('JOHN_'\@NAME\'_SMITH'); `
 while executing it throws below error :

`ERROR 1048 (23000) at line 5 in file: 'C:/abc.sql': Column 'Name' cannot be null'. How to place @NAME in between the NAME value JOHN SMITH? It should look like JOHN_XYZ_SMITH

Comment: Try using [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), like `CONCAT('JOHN_', @NAME, '_SMITH')` - also, for additional questions you should post as a new question, not as a comment.